# Magento not creating order for M2Epro Orders

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

I have implemented M2Epro with magento.

I have used  Ebay_Available_quantity attribute to set ebay available quantity.

But there are time where website normal stock is zero and product is out of stock and its still listing on ebay.

When someone buys it on ebay. It does make an order on M2Epro. But does not allow to make order as a magento order.

Is it because it is out of stock or quantity is zero ?

Can we have exceptions for third party sales ?

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: We hit the same issue on our site. It appears that Magento will not create orders for products that are out of stock. I haven't found a workaround.

Comment: @Enigmativity : It is such a sad story :(  can't figure my way around.

Comment: Did you try to set "Backorders allowed" in your store configuration?

Answer (score 0):

We also encountered this issue some time ago and this is what M2e answered on an email:

> Thank you for provided details.
>
> I checked your FBA order XXXX and I understand that you
>   want Magento order creation for FBA orders do not depend on stock
>   availability.
>
> Let me please explain the logic how Magento orders are created.  When
>   a channel order is imported in M2e Pro, M2e Pro checks settings
>   provided in Account settings > Orders tab. If corresponding settings
>   for Magento order creation are provided - M2E Pro sends a request to
>   Magento to create a Magento order for the channel order.
>
> Magento orders are created due to Standard Magento functionality and
>   Core Models. Magento does not let to create an order if the product is
>   out of stock or 'disabled' or does not have available qty in Magento.
>   These requirements should be met so that the order was successfully
>   created.
>
> M2e Pro cannot affect the logic of Magento orders creation process.
>   You can temporarily set 'in stock' status and qty available if you
>   want Magento order to be created at one for FBA order.
>
> Hope this explanation will be helpful. Please let me know if I can
>   assist you with something else.

Next email:

> Other our customers use backorders feature.  As a possible workaround
>   for creation orders when product quantity is 0, you can allow for
>   needed products (product should be in stock, manage quantity - "yes".
>   This will allow Magento order creation for corresponding FBA order if
>   qty=0. You can set this parameter in Magento product inventory.
>
> I have consulted with our development department on your case. As a
>   possible workaround, we can provide you with a part of the code which
>   is responsible for orders functionality. If your developers would be
>   able to adjust the needed changes, we would be glad to assist you.
>   Please also note, that we will not guarantee the proper work when some
>   custom modifications to the code are applied. In case this suggestion
>   is approved by your developers, please send us your confirmation and I
>   will send you a part of the code.

The code they wanted to provide was useless, it was just a hint that the magic happens in

```
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Order.php
public function createMagentoOrder()
```

which is quite obvious.

Please consider that backorders feature will bring other issues, so we do not use this and currently live with this situation as it is.

For me it is a quite important and standard situation to have FBA stock but no magento stock, so I don't understand why they don't fix the problem.

When time is available we will do a fix ourselves.